# How to use context.WithCancel and context.WithTimeout API together, and is it necessary?

Tags: go

Now I did something like this:

```
func contextHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(r.Context())
        ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, config.EnvConfig.RequestTimeout)

        defer cancel()

        if cn, ok := w.(http.CloseNotifier); ok {
            go func(done <-chan struct{}, closed <-chan bool) {
                select {
                case <-done:
                case <-closed:
                    logger.Debug("message", "client connection has gone away, request will be cancelled")
                    cancel()
                }
            }(ctx.Done(), cn.CloseNotify())
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

Pls pay attention to these two lines:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(r.Context())
ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, config.EnvConfig.RequestTimeout)
```

According to my tests: `deliberately kill the client request` and `deliberately make the request exceed the deadline`, both are working fine(i mean can receive the cancellation signal and timeout signal as expected), just my concern is: the latter `cancel` function will override the previous one returned by the `context.WithCancel(r.Context())`, so:

1. Is it a proper way to use these two APIs together like this?
2. Is it even necessary to use these two APIs together?

Please help to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `CancelFunc` returned from your `WithCancel` call is being immediately overwritten, this causes a resource (i.e. memory) leak in your program. From the [context documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context):

> The WithCancel, WithDeadline, and WithTimeout functions take a Context (the parent) and return a derived Context (the child) and a CancelFunc. Calling the CancelFunc cancels the child and its children, removes the parent's reference to the child, and stops any associated timers. **Failing to call the CancelFunc leaks the child and its children until the parent is canceled or the timer fires.**

Removing the `WithCancel` context from your code will fix this problem.

Additionally, cancellation of the HTTP request is managed by the HTTP server, as described in the [`http.Request.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) method documentation:

> For incoming server requests, the context is canceled when the client's connection closes, the request is canceled (with HTTP/2), or when the ServeHTTP method returns.

When the server cancels the request context, all child contexts will be cancelled.

Comment: can u help to explain a bit after remove the `WithCancel` how the `deliberately kill the client request` scenario works? is it because of the go http module already created the context with `WithCancel` and called the `defer cancel()`?

Comment: No there is no resource leak here. The stack frame, or gc, will release the resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `WithTimeout()`, instead of using both APIs, because `WithTimeout()` returns you a `context.CancelFunc` just as `WithCancel()` does, which could be called at any time to cancel the target process/routine. Of course, the cancellation should before hitting the deadline set by `WithTimeout()`.

So,

> Is it a proper way to use these two APIs together like this?
>    Is it even necessary to use these two APIs together?

No, no need to use both, use returned `context.CancelFunc` by any API in package context.